# Cannot use import statement outside a module in cucumber.js for private npm package

Tags: typescript, cucumberjs

I am using `cucumberjs` for testing several components of my project which works. However in one step I use a `zod` schema which is defined in a private npm module:

```
// in private npm package:
// constant.js
import { z } from 'zod';
export const ROLES = z.enum([
    'ROLE_USER',
    'ROLE_EMPLOYEE',
    'ROLE_MANAGER',
]);
```

This npm package is installed in an upper level and I receive the following error:

```
/Users/../node_modules/@privateModule/schemas/lib/constants.js:1
import { z } from 'zod';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I don't understand why every other module seems to work but not this one.

This is the `tsconfig.json` from the testing component:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "core/*": ["../core/src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

and this the the config from the parent folder:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node18/tsconfig.json"
}
```

It looks like whenever I want to import anything from this private module a similar error happens.

As requested the `package.json` file of the private module: (I removed the dependencies, name and author and scrips)

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "exports": {
  "./functions": "./dist/functions/index.js",
    "./schemas": "./dist/schemas/index.js",
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
},
  "typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "functions": [
      "dist/functions/index.d.ts"
    ],
      "schemas": [
      "dist/schemas/index.d.ts"
    ],
      "*": [
      "dist/index.d.ts"
    ]
  }
},
  
}
```

As for the `package.json` for the compenent which runs the test: There is nothing in there besides name, version, description, scripts and dependencies.

Comment: Please show your typescript config

Comment: I added the tsconfig in the question

Comment: This issue is discussed on the cucumberjs github repo in this thread: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/2338

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's due to plugin issue itself from their side so can you please downgrade the package version as they mentioned here https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/347.

Comment: I tried to downgrade to several versions after 3.0.0-alpha30 and I also tried to upgrade it to the latest. Without any success

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I've tried to setup the new project with typescript and install "zod": "^3.22.4" plugin but unable replicate issue that you are mentioned

Comment: I think this is not zod related, I was under the assumption that it was because the private module contains alot of schemas and when I import a schema the first import on the file where this schema is defined is often zod. 
But when I for example import 'myClass' from `myClass.js` of that private module I get the error for the first import of `myClass.js` which could be something totally different.
My assumption is, that its some setup of `cucumberjs` I am missing